# Jurafsky and Martin (2018) Do not understand formula in naiye bayes classifier

Tags: mathematical-statistics, natural-language, naive-bayes

Currently I am reading [Language and Speech Processing by , Chapter 4 Naiye Bayes and Sentiment Classification](https://web.stanford.edu/~jurafsky/slp3/4.pdf). 
At page $7,$ when the authors discuss worked example.
Data set is as follows:

Training set: 
just plain boring (-)

entirely predictable and lacks energy (-)

no surprises and very few laughs (-)

very powerful (+)

the most fun film of the summer (+)

Test
predictable with no fun (?)

---

I fail to understand why is $20$ added in the denominator, i.e.
$$P( \text{'prediction'} | -) = \frac{1+1}{14+20}.$$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you look at equation (4.14) on page 6, you see that 20 is actually $|V|$ that is the total number of words in the vocabulary.

So now, if you look at the training set and count the number of **unique** words, you will find that they are 20.

HTH

Comment: I see. It is the number of unique words, not the total number of words, which include duplicate words?

Comment: yes - it is _"the **union** of all the words types in all classes"_